# Flask-SQLAlchemy won't update or delete a row

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to either update a row in the database, if it exists, or create it if it doesn't.

I have a class that first sets the instance variable `user`:

```
self.user = models.User.query.filter_by(entity=self.entityUrl).first()
# can be None if not found
```

Then, later on in another class method I do this:

```
if self.user is not None:
    self.user.foo = bar  # etc. Change the attributes of self.user
else:
    self.user = models.User(bar, ... )  # create a new model
    db.session.add(self.user)
db.session.commit()
```

Problem is, the corresponding row in the database doesn't get updated. I've also tried this approach:

```
if self.user is not None:
    self.user.foo = bar
else:
    self.user = models.User(bar, ... )
db.session.add(self.user)  # add it to the session either way
db.session.commit()
```

Here, the db.session.add() call fails with `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Object '<User at 0x7f4918172890>' is already attached to session '1' (this is '2')`

And the first thing I tried was to delete the existing model in all cases, then create a new one, i.e.:

```
if self.user is not None:
    db.session.delete(self.user)
self.user = models.User(bar, ... )
db.session.add(self.user)
db.session.commit()
```

In this case the db.session.delete() call fails with the same `already attached to session '1'` message as above.

Why is the object attached to a different session and not the same one? How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the foo attribute in your class existes. Next, maybe there is something wrong in the way you use it. Because I see you use "self.user....". Try the simplest thing first. Then step by step.

The following code is wrong:

```
if self.user is not None:
    self.user.foo = bar
else:
    self.user = models.User(bar, ... )
db.session.add(self.user)  # add it to the session either way
db.session.commit()
```

NO need to `db.session.add`, if you want to update the record.

Answer (score -1):

To update existing record using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you do not need to re-create the entire User object and add it to the session. You just update the specific field (e.g. foo) and thats it. You can then do the db commit.

You can do your exact requirement as below:

## Step 1: query the existing user object

```
user = models.User.query.filter_by(entity=self.entityUrl).first()
```

## Step 2:

```
if user is not None:
     user.foo = bar
else:
    user = User(...)
    db.session.add(user)
```

## Step 3: commit the db session.

```
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: That's exactly what my code is doing except that Step 1 is in a different method from Steps 2-3. And the DB doesn't update. I'll see if I can reduce it to a minimal example.

Comment: Ok I thought you said " # add it to the session either way". That might be the issue. You only want to add it to the session if it is a new user. In my step 2, i m only adding to the session in the else block. Are you doing the same ?

Comment: As mentioned, I tried both ways. If I add it to the session when modifying it, I get an error (which agrees with what you're saying). If I don't, it doesn't update.

Comment: " Step 1 is in a different method from Steps 2-3". Perhaps the user object is not passed correctly to the next steps. You might want to check the method. May be post code for it here ?